# c# - vcvars32 errors out trying to compile class into dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, compilation

I'm trying to compile a c# class (myClass, which implements ImyInterface) into a dll using vcvars32.

I get error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ImyInterface' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Has anybody ran into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: it's not `vcvars32` which is failing here; it's the C# compiler which is giving an error. You may have run `vcvars32` in order to set up your environment, but that's very different.

> Has anybody ran into this problem?

Only when trying to refer to a type that the C# compiler doesn't know about. As the error message says, check your `using` directives (to make sure you're importing all the namespaces you need) and your assembly references (to make sure you have a reference to the assembly containing `ImyInterface`).

Also check your spelling - `ImyInterface` would usually be `IMyInterface`, and C# is case-sensitive.

If `ImyInterface` doesn't exist within an existing library which you're referencing - in other words, if you're trying to build that interface into the same assembly - then you'll need to include the source file containing the interface declaration on the command line.

That's about all we can say with no further information about where the interface is, what namespace it's in, what namespace your class is in, etc.

Comment: How do you include the source file on the command line? --Thanks

Comment: @user1481183: The same way you're already including the one that contains `myClass`, so something like `csc Foo.cs Bar.cs`. Is there any reason you're compiling from the command line rather than using Visual Studio?